# Problema usando cv::Imread

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

Estoy escribiendo un código para leer todas las imágenes de una carpeta y después escribir la información de las imágenes en un binario todas juntas. El problema es que cuando uso la función `cv::imread` el campo .data de la `cv::MAT` siempre se queda nulo, y cuando voy a escribir hay error al acceder a un puntero nulo.
Estoy utilizando rutas absolutas obtenidos de un fichero `.txt` en el siguiente código:

```
void main(){
  const unsigned int SizeImg = 1024 * 768 * sizeof(char);
  std::ifstream file;
  file.open("files.txt", std::ios::out);
  std::string line;
  std::string files[50];
  std::string imagen;
  std::ofstream Binary("Images.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  int n = 0;
  while (std::getline(file,line))
  {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
    files[n] = line;
    n++;
  }
  file.close();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    imagen = files[i];
    cv::Mat m = cv::imread(imagen, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
    //cv::imshow("ventana", m);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    Binary.write((char*)m.data, SizeImg);
  }
  Binary.close();
}
```

Estoy empezando con *OpenCV* así que puede que haya otras cosas que no estén muy bien tampoco.

Comment: Según [la documentación](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) si `cv::imread` devuelve null es porque no ha podido abrir la imagen, verifica las rutas.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), cito:

> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).

El problema es que la función no es capaz de abrir el fichero, ya sea porque el nombre y/o la ruta son incorrectos, por falta de permisos o por intentar abrir un formato no soportado.

Yo empezaría por imprimir la ruta del fichero para ver si la ruta es válida. Ojo en este punto si te da por usar rutas relativas... el directorio de trabajo de la aplicación no tiene porqué ser el mismo que el directorio donde se encuentra el ejecutable...

Comment: Las rutas las he comprobado y están bien, en el código que he proporcionado antes las rutas las escribí en el `.txt` utilizando la función `glob.glob` de python para obtenerlas. Pero he probado a insertar la ruta en el código directamente usando tanto `/` como \ y no me funciono. También he leído en la documentación que el formato de las imágenes `.pgm` esta soportado por las librerías de OpenCV, no se si el problema es que windows no es capaz de trabajar con este formato.

Comment: @EmilioLiaño pon un png o un jpg en la misma carpeta y prueba a leerlo. Si eres capaz de leerlo entonces es problema del formato... si no lo mismo tienes un problema de permisos (o hay algo en la ruta que se te está escapando)

Comment: he probado a leer una `.jpg` y tampoco ha podido leerla. Yo creo que las rutas que estoy usando están bien pero no puedo estar seguro si falla tanto. ¿Algún truco para comprobar que las rutas están bien, hay alguna ruta que pueda saber seguro que esta bien para probar con esa?

Comment: @EmilioLiaño revisa los permisos de acceso de la carpeta. Prueba si no a cargar las imágenes desde una carpeta que esté directamente en C, como `C:\temp`

Comment: Este es el nuevo codigo que estoy probando: `cv::Mat prueba = cv::imread("C:/Temp/Captura.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
cv::imshow("PRUEBA", prueba);
cv::waitKey(0);` he revisado mis permisos en esa carpeta y tengo lectura y escritura, tambien he probado a leer la imagen sin flags sin resultado

Comment: @EmilioLiaño antes de llamar a `imshow` deberías comprobar que `prueba.data != 0`. Además, creo recordar que antes de llamar a `imshow` hay que crear la ventana con `cv::namedWindow("PRUEBA",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`

Comment: Las rutas son correctas, porque cuando he probado a abrir el fichero con `fopen` he podido acceder a las imágenes como ficheros con permiso de escritura, pero debe haber algún conflicto con los permisos. Cuando intento acceder a estos ficheros con permisos de lectura devuelve un puntero nulo `fopen`. pero he revisado los permisos en **propiedades>seguridad** y debería tener todos los permisos de escritura y lectura para esos ficheros.

Comment: @EmilioLiaño lo mismo es un problema de instalación o configuración de opencv... lo mismo no se están cargando los drivers de los formatos gráficos y por eso opencv es incapaz de abrir las imágenes